# Can I use an extra 'etc' folder inside /usr in linux?

Tags: linux, lfs, stow

I'm experimenting with linux from scratch. I'm using stow to install extra packages into `/usr/local/stow/`. I'm using the command `stow <package dir> -t /usr` which symlinks everythin to `/usr/bin, /usr/lib, /usr/share,` etcetara. But this also creates a folder `/usr/etc`. To my knowledge '`etc`' folder is inside root folder, `/`. So, my question is, will the package work if the configuration files are inside `/usr/etc` instead of `/etc` ?

Comment: Probably not. Read `man hier`.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, it should link into `/etc`.

Comment: I don't know anything about `stow`, but it would seem to me that `/opt` is the proper place for packages it is managing (regardless of what they say), *not* `/usr/local/[anything]`.

Comment: @vonbrand  It kinda is, I just saw and old thread on github.